# Reloading listview displays old and new content

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a custom listview that displays the contents of a database table.
The use can add a new item to the database and the Listview will reload to display the newly added item as well as everything else in the table.

However using the below code when the listview is updated it will show both the content from the table for the add and after the add. For example:

The list view would look like:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

Then a user adds a new item and it should look like

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
```

But instead it displays

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
```

I use this code to update the Listview

```
 m_adapter.clear();
 for (int i = 0; i < db.getAllLists().size(); i++) {
       m_adapter.add(db.getAllLists().get(i));
 }
 m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Mylistadapter

```
class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<mList> {

        private ArrayList<mList> items;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<mList> items) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
                this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
                }
                mList o = items.get(position);
                if (o != null) {
                        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ptitle);
                        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Asap-Regular.ttf");  
                        tt.setTypeface(font);  

                        if (tt != null) {
                              tt.setText(o.getName() + " (" + db.getItemsCount(o.getID()) + ")");                            
                            }
                }
                return v;
        }
    }
```

And then the below code is in my oncreate:

```
    ArrayList<mList> m_orders = db.getAllLists();

    MyListAdapter m_adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row_layout, m_orders);
    ListView list1.setAdapter(m_adapter);
```

Let me know if you need to see any other code, thank you

EDIT
Also tried

```
 m_orders.clear();
 m_orders = db.getAllLists();
 m_adapter.addAll(m_orders);
 m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

However it still shows both the old and new list

Comment: It seems that the old list is not cleared, and you add the old plus the new. Maybe your m_adapter.clear() does not do the work properly. Post more code ?

Comment: @Yume117 more cost posted

Comment: How about clearing the ArrayList (instead of the adapter) and then adding the new items in the ArrayList and then calling notifyDatasetChanged() ? I mean, that is how I do it and it never fails me.

Comment: @swayam tried (See update) prehaps you could give me a sample of the code you use

Comment: It is pretty much the same, except for the fact that my code is usually in AsyncTask. I clear the ArrayList in preExecute, add the elements to the arraylist in background and notifyDatasetChanged in postExecute.

Comment: If it's still not working and you don't find some wherearound, do some log, check your list size then and then...

Answer (score 0):

//First clear the collection (Arraylist in your case)

```
your_collection.clear();
```

// Add the new data like

```
ArrayList<mList> m_orders = db.getAllLists();
```

// then refresh the listview using

```
m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```